# I am trying to install gulp on linux kubuntu but i have such problem

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install

I installed node and npm but I cant install gulp

after successfully installing node and npm I tried `npm install -g gulp`

````
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dilmurod/.npm/_logs/2019-03-30T09_01_16_977Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: You need root access to install packages globally. Run it with sudo - `sudo npm install -g gulp`

Comment: The error log couldn't be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you run `npm install package_name -g` with g flag, it gets stored in **/usr/lib/node_modules/** folder

This error comes if the current user, who is executing the command `npm install -g` doesn't have the write permission to /usr/lib/

Execute this with **root user** or `sudo npm install gulp -g`